# Velocidad máxima para USB 3.2 Gen 2x1 con PCI-E 3.0 x16

Tags: usb

Estoy haciendo ampliaciones en el PC y quería adquirir una controladora para USB 3.2 Gen 2x1 que tiene una velocidad max. teórica de 10Gbps. Mi placa es Asus Z170-A que con PCI-E 3.0 podría alcanzar 8Gbps.

Si adquiero una controladora USB de x8 o x16, al tener más canales y aumentar el ancho de banda, ¿podría alcanzar ese límite de 8Gbps que soporta o me seguiría quedando en 5Gbps?.

Según los tests que he realizado:

- A través de USB-C de mi placa (sin uso de tarjeta de expansión), para un SSD da como resultados:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- A través de una controladora USB 3.0 SuperSpeed PCI-E, me da resultados análogos para el SSD

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo que no llegaría ni a 4 Gbps de velocidad :-(. ¿Es posible que esto mejorara adquiriendo una controladora PCI-E 3.0 x16 para USB 3.2 Gen 2x1?. Dicha controladora da hasta 10 Gbps de velocidad max. teórica, por lo tanto alcanzaría los 8Gbps que brinda PCI-E 3.0 (según las indicaciones de CPU-Z.

Muchas gracias!

Comment: SO es para preguntas de programación, no de sistemas. Te recomiendo preguntar en algún sitio como serverFault, donde se trabaje con sistemas.

Comment: la pregunta no es para este foro sin embargo, te puedo decir que hay muchas cosas que pueden hacer un cuello de botella por ejemplo que tu unidad tenga un ssd antiguo y no soporte altas velocidades ahora si es un ssd jamas tomara mayores velocidades, para eso debe ser un nvme no sata, y que la controladora soporte usb c 3.2, por si sola la pc podria soportar altas velocidades, podrias poner mas detalles de la unidad SSD? antes que borren tu pregunsta jejeje

Comment: Muchas gracias :-). Lo trasladaré al otro foro. John, los SSD son actuales de WD y Samsung, las velocidades teóricas de ambos son de hasta 560MBps, los probé en SATA directo y alcanza velocidades mucho más elevadas que por mi USB C actual. Por lo que probaré a meter alguna controladora de las que comenté. Un saludo!